# Azure Function: use parameter for SqlQuery from ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-http-trigger

I store `ClaimsPrincipal` inside `FunctionContext.IInvocationFeatures` list (inside auth middleware) and want to take a `userId` (key: `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`) as an argument to cosmosDb query. I can do it inside a function with this pseudo code:

```
 var allFeatures = ((HttpRequestData)req).FunctionContext.Features;
 var claimsPrincipalHolderFeature = allFeatures.First(..);
 var id = claimsPrincipalHolderFeature.Claims.First(c =>
     c.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
 ).Value;
 // steps with CosmosClient
```

But I want to do it via `CosmosDbInput` attribute, something like:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "area")] HttpRequestData req,
    [CosmosDBInput(
        databaseName: "%CosmosDb%",
        containerName: "%CosmosContainer%",
        Connection = "CosmosDBConnection",
        SqlQuery = $"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM area a WHERE a.objectId = {{ClaimsPrincipal.Claims[{ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier}]}}")] List<Model> areas)
```

unfortunatelly this template`{ClaimsPrincipal.Claims[{ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier}]}` doesn't work, does anyone have any suggestions? If it's not possible and I need to implement custom bindings, it would be good to reuse some already existed code (CosmosDBInputAttribute and related code) and not create anything from scratch like for example described [here](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip247.html)

Answer (score 2):

Bindings can use Expressions coming from other Bindings, for example, you can use something from the `HttpTrigger` into the `CosmosDBInput`, but from the environment, I see no documentation stating that it's possible.

Values can be bound from:

- App settings
- Trigger file name
- Trigger metadata
- JSON payloads (for example what is coming from the HttpTrigger)
- New GUID
- Current date and time

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns